# Target a div, skipping it's parent

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to target `.div-3` directly, if it's parent doesn't have and id/class?

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="div-3">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I know I can do `.wrapper > div > div > .div-3`, but is it possible to have something like `.wrapper > .div-3` ?

Comment: Like `.wrapper .div-3` ?

Comment: @LcSalazar And I was always thinking it targets the first child :\ Thanks a lot, you can post it as a answer.

Comment: Thats ok... Glad I could help... If you want, you can select the already answered one... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/rg256czf/)

You could use

```
.wrapper .div-3
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

> The selector `A E` selects any `E` element that is a descendant of an
>   `A` element (that is: a child, or a child of a child, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.div-3` only.

```
.div-3{

}
```